# ROR deployment on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!

```
Exception while executing on host 53.45.43.233: rvm exit status: 142
rvm stdout: Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
rvm stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => rvm:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am trying to deploy a ror project to EC2 and getting this error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should run RVM as the user who owns the code. example here ubuntu

Edit the Capistrano deployment script to use ubuntu as a user. You can do this by setting the user variable in the deploy.rb file.

Try this. There is no much log exits to know the reason. Hope this will help

Ex:

```
set :user, "server-user-name"
```